# Twilio voice calling with schedule calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, ivr

We are building a voice calling application ie (https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-ios#11-make-client-to-client-call), calling working good with great sound quality. We have a new requirement to schedule a call outside of the application,  ie instead of the call occurring through the application, it will occur by a normal dial-in number.

**Our use case as follows**

1. Caller clicks on agents profile.
2. The caller sees a list of available dates/times that agents are available. Let's say April 10th at 1 pm PST is available.
3. Caller selects April 10th at 1 pm and presses "Schedule".
4. The caller is prompted to pay $100 for a 1-hour call at the selected time.
5. The caller enters credit card information and presses "Pay".
6. The caller sees a confirmation message:

> Your call is now booked with John Smith! Please call (555-555-5555 -
>   Twilio number) at 1 pm on April 10th, 2020.

We want to know the following

If a user calls to a Twilio number, can we redirect that call to our agents(ie we have several registered agents in our application)

When users calling, we want to know who is calling and where to redirect this call.

I think we can manage scheduling with our application logic. Let us know, what all services Twilio provides for executing such a scenario, we would love to know is there is any other way around. Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at products such as Twilio Studio. Studio allows you to easily set-up a [call forwarding scenario](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding), but the hyperlinked article has many way to accomplish this task. It sounds like you have already built out the agent assignment functionality.